# LabelEncoding a Dataframe

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe with integer and categorical variables. Should I label encode all variables (both integer and categorical) or should I encode only the categorical features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to label encode the categorical features. For e.g. if the first column contains categorical data then you can do something like shown below-

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
x[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(x[:, 0])
```